# Opening a new Instance of the same activity

Tags: android

i'm working on a ToDo List app , so i'm using MVVM architecture , recyclerview with adapter , in my main activity the user adds a new value in a position , so depending on position i want to open an new instance of the same activty everytime where the user can insert different data , is there a possible way to do that !
*For example : first position : First TASK , when the user clicks on First task , it opens new instance of the other activity where the user adds unique data according to that position , if the user adds : Second TASK
he clicks again on it , he opens new instance of the same and add unique data too , hopefully it is clear , thank you for help in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? What point are you failing at?

Comment: Well i m not getting the way to do i have intent which opens that activity ( the same activity should opened everytime to insert new data according to position click) so if user clicks position 1 , goes to the next activity , add unique data , then he goes back and click the second position , he goes back again to that activity and  it should be empty and add unique data to it and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what you're trying to achieve is quite simple: Add a button (a floating action button preferably)  that let users  create a new task: the button will open an activity or fragment in which you present the users with task details to fill, then at the end, save that task into a db then return to the task list Activity/Fragment there load saved tasks from db.

You can also give possibility to modify already exist task, etc